# Symfony 5 and varnish

Tags: varnish, symfony5

I installed varnish on my server, it's active (checked via the sudo systemctl varnish restart command). I configured the /etc/varnish/default.vcl file following the tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/varnish.html but I don't have the impression that varnish is taken into account on Symfony (I don't see X-Varnish in the response header (however it appears well when I access directly to my server via http://localhost/.

Here is my default.vcl file:

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.
 
# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;
 
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
 
sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto == "https" ) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Port = "443";
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Port = "80";
    }
 
    # Remove all cookies except the session ID.
    if (req.http.Cookie) {
        set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(PHPSESSID)=", "; \1=");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");
 
        if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
            // If there are no more cookies, remove the header to get page cached.
            unset req.http.Cookie;
        }
    }
 
    # Add a Surrogate-Capability header to announce ESI support.
    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";
}
 
sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
 
    # Check for ESI acknowledgement and remove Surrogate-Control header
    if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
}
 
sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

Maybe then there is something to configure on symfony but I don't see what. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're unsure that Varnish is correctly handling requests, you should check if the `varnishd` process runs on the right TCP port.

You can do this by running the following command:

```
sudo systemctl status varnish
```

In my case, this is the output:

```
● varnish.service - Varnish Cache Plus, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-04-09 17:50:00 UTC; 3min 5s ago
 Main PID: 1242 (varnishd)
    Tasks: 226
   CGroup: /system.slice/varnish.service
           ├─1242 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -a 127.0.0.1:8443,proxy -S /etc/varnish/secret -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s mse,/etc/varnish/mse.conf
           └─1256 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -a 127.0.0.1:8443,proxy -S /etc/varnish/secret -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s mse,/etc/varnish/mse.conf
```

The relevant information is the command that is executed, along with the runtime options and paramters.

In this case `varnishd` is listening for incoming connections on 2 ports:

- `80` for regular HTTP traffic
- `8443` for PROXY traffic

In your case, the listening ports may be configured differently.

Out the box, these are the default values:

```
/usr/sbin/varnishd \
      -a :6081 \
      -a localhost:8443,PROXY \
      -p feature=+http2 \
      -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
      -s malloc,256m
```

As you can see port `6081` is used for incoming HTTP traffic. You may need to change this to port `80`.

Just run the following command to edit the unit file:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full varnish
```

Once you've adjusted the runtime parameters, just run the following command to restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart varnish
```

> **WARNING:** if you run Varnish on the same server as the webserver, you will need to change the listening port of the webserver as well. A good option is port `8080`.

Comment: So my config is : DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \  -T localhost:6082 \ -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \ -S /etc/varnish/secret \ -s malloc,256m". I need to add -a 127.0.0.1:8000 ? Because symfony's projets turns on 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @yinyang I guess you're a bit confused: `-a` defines listeners for incoming requests from clients. What you're trying to do is to connect Varnish to Symfony. This interaction is done using a `backend` definition in your `default.vcl` file. See http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vcl.html#backend-definition for more information about backends.

Comment: I have already a backend definition in my default.vcl : backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

Comment: @yinyang Great, just follow my instructions to make sure incoming requests to Varnish happen using the right ports. I would advise you to run the Varnish server on port 80.